# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

getting the exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

i tried [NoClassDefFoundError with libraries in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620635/noclassdeffounderror-with-libraries-in-android-studio)

./gradlew clean is successful from terminal

still i am getting same exception

Comment: Post the entire exception please.

Comment: @Digit have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy the Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` which threw the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. In your libraries, some classes may be a descendant of an Activity which need to be manifested in the `AndroidManifest.xml` when you want to call it.

Comment: i have added all Activities in manifest,its a working code previously