# No Class Def Found Error org.apache.ContentType (Android Studio)

Tags: android, apache, networking

Good Day.I done heaps of researches and used every answer i found but nothing helped!Im trying to upload simple image to php server in bytes with this code

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    String fileName = String.format("File_%d.png", new Date().getTime());
    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, fileName);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.100/paqqy/user/registration/platform/android");

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(

            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);
```

Whats funny is that the damned android studio keeps giving me NoClassDefFound Error at line of `ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, fileName);` but i did try everything...Rebuilding,Cleaning,Gradle Sync,download all versions of HttpMime,HttpCore,HttpCore-cache and so on...but still this freaking android studio will give it to me.In eclipse it was easy,was using order and export in that case and error had gun,but here i just dont know what to do,please help me a little im so angry and desperate!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError with libraries in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620635/noclassdeffounderror-with-libraries-in-android-studio)

Comment: Did NOT WORKED FOR ME I DID SAID I TRY EVERYTHING!!!!!!i have read that post too and did not help me!